# How to get a user role

Tags: java, documentum

I have a project based on documentum, and after user login I'd like to know what's his role.
The reason is that there is a requirment for a menu-action to be enabled just for users who has the specific role.
Assume I have the username (being taken from the login page), how can I do this?
Do I have to put this data on session once the user logged in? I'd prefer to have a one line code that could be called from the client side (javascript) and on the fly doing the disabling of the menu action.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Use the correct tag. Plus your question is really unclear because not many people know what documentum is. If you want to know the role of a user, store it in the object/class of the user variable or store it in the database(?) that you check for login

Comment: WDK (Webtop, xCP 1.x?) or Ext JS (xCP 2.x)? Your question is so unspecific as like we are talking about football which can be european, american or australian.

Answer (score 0):

When you login at that service u can create a JSON which will have value of which all menus are enabled for the logged in user.Now when the screen loads with menus u can use this JSON data to hide/display or enable/disable the menu items.
Or else u can write a scriplet tag in the the disables attribute and in the scriplet tag you can call a class static method which returns true or false based in the user details sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following condition to determine the role of a user. I have provided it as a DQL, but you can use the logic to fit it in your code.

```
select group_name from dm_group where any i_all_users_names = "user_name"
```

Hope this helps.